# Keeping older mixin while utilzing Bootstrap 4's spacing utilities

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I have an application that is several years old that uses Bootstrap 4, as well as a custom mixin, for spacing. The mixin.scss is as follows:

```
$sides: (top, left, bottom, right);

@each $prop in $props {
  .#{str-slice($prop, 0, 1)}-0 {
    #{$prop}: 0 !important;
  }

  @each $side in $sides {
    .#{str-slice($prop, 0, 1)}#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-0 {
      #{$prop}-#{$side}: 0 !important;
    }
  }

  @for $i from 1 through 16 {
    .#{str-slice($prop, 0, 1)}-#{$i*2} {
      #{$prop}: #{$i * 2}px !important;
    }

    @each $side in $sides {
      .#{str-slice($prop, 0, 1)}#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{$i*2} {
        #{$prop}-#{$side}: #{$i * 2}px !important;
      }
    }

    .#{str-slice($prop, 0, 1)}x-#{$i*2} {
      #{$prop}: 0 #{$i * 2}px !important;
    }

    .#{str-slice($prop, 0, 1)}y-#{$i*2} {
      #{$prop}: #{$i * 2}px 0 !important;
    }
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through 20 {
  .w-#{$i*5} {
    width: #{$i * 5%} !important;
  }
}
```

This seems to affect only even numbers, which is fine. But I would like to use Bootstrap 4's spacing utilities which are based on numbers 1-5 (i.e., `mt-3` for `margin-top:16px`), while *also* keeping some of the higher numbers available (I have found `mt-24` and `mt-32` throughout the app).

How would I update the current `_mixin.scss` to essentially ignore any margin/padding set to 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, and let bootstrap 4 handle that?